# How can a base class reference a supertype and still compile?

Tags: c#

how does this class compile?

```
public class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static IReflectionHelper CreateHelper( object subject )
    {
        return ( IReflectionHelper )Activator.CreateInstance( typeof( ReflectionHelper<> ).MakeGenericType( GetFirstGenericArgument( subject ) ) );
    }
    public static Type GetFirstGenericArgument( object subject )
    {
        return subject.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
    }
}

public class ReflectionHelper<T> : ReflectionHelper, IReflectionHelper where T : new()
    {}
```

Notice ReflectionHelper`<T>` inherits from ReflectionHelper which has a referance to the type of ReflectionHelper<>
For some reason I was expecting a circular reference compile error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how does this class compile?

Very well, thank you.

> For some reason I was expecting a circular reference compile error.

I'm not sure why you'd expect that. The circumstances in which you get a circular reference error are:

1) circular references involving base class loops:

```
class C : B {}
class B : C {}
```

Interestingly enough, a strict reading of the C# 2.0 spec did not actually make

```
class C : C {}
```

illegal, though of course the compiler caught this one. We've corrected the spec.

2) similar circular references involving "base interface" loops

3) circularities in type parameter constraints:

```
class C<T, U> where T : U 
              where U : T
```

4) circularities in enum members:

```
enum E { A = B, B = A }
```

Note also that it is illegal for an outer class to inherit from an inner class, though the reverse is legal.

Those are the ones that immediately come to mind. I think I'm missing one or two though.

There are some known bugs in the C# cycle detectors. For example, the compiler flags this as a cycle error, even though it is not:

```
class November<T> {}
class Romeo : November<Romeo.Sierra.Tango>
{
    class Sierra { class Tango { } }
}
```

I designed and implemented an improved cycle detection algorithm for C# 4, but unfortunately the fix was so complex and far-reaching within the compiler implementation that we decided to punt on it for C# 4, rather than take on the testing burden of verifying the rather large change. The cases which are actually made illegal incorrectly are obscure and do not come up in real-world applications very often.

However, your case certainly has no cycle in it. Why do you believe there is a cycle?

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to elaborate on your "some reason" for us to say why it's not actually a problem. Circular references exist all over the place in .NET - they're not a problem, so long as it's within the same assembly. For a simpler non-generic example:

```
// Compiles with no problem
class Foo
{
    Bar other;
}

class Bar
{
    Foo other;
}
```

(There are actually circular *assembly* references within the BCL... but that's just nasty and evil.)

Comment: I think the question is more of "how is this even possible?" When coming from other languages, this kind of circular reference isn't possible. My brain hurts when I look at the attributes applied to the Attribute class.

Comment: The compiler loads enough information from all of the classes it's going to compile before it tries to compile the rest, I imagine. Fortunately we don't have the constraints of older languages :)